# Google Vision API service account permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I want to use `Google Vision API` with service account. The problem is that there is no role to give access to `Vision API` only, the only role I've found is `owner` role which is too powerful.

Is there is any role to give access only to `Vision API` or other way to give app permission without giving full access to GCP project?

Comment: Who is the service account for (yourself, developers, end users) and where does this code run? What other services require access (Cloud Vision often requires Google Cloud Storage access). You have two choices, use the role Cloud Viewer, or create a custom service account OAuth Access Token limited to the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision`. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: This is account for backend app. Actually this app already has service account.
I've tried to use OAuth2 tokens, but didn't understand how to get rid of user prompt to authorise access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no specific role for the Vision API. As indicated on the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/setup#auth) it is advised to use the Owner role (which I totally agree that could be very dangerous to use). There are at least two Feature Requests [1](https://issuetracker.google.com/155913349) [2](https://issuetracker.google.com/156731491) opened on the Issue Tracker which I recommend you to star and comment upon for such a role to be implemented. In the meantime you can follow the recommendation offered by @johnhanley on the comment.

Comment: from the GCP docs linked _The Vision API itself requires a service account, but doesn't require you to create a role to be used. Any valid service account can call the Vision API on a project that enables the API._

Answer (score 4):

There is no role needed for Vision API. I would recommend having no roles on the service account.

Comment: this is supposed to be the accepted answer